# React Testing-Library testing DOM changes on event fire

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library, testing-library

Given the following component (`<Button>` is a custom component that's `<button>`-like)

```
const MyElement = ({
    onRemove,
}) => {
    const [isRemoving, setIsRemoving] = useState(false);

    const handleRemove = (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        setIsRemoving(true);
        onRemove().finally(() => setIsRemoving(false));
    };

    return (
        <Button
            status={isRemoving ? 'busy' : 'selected'}
            onClick={handleRemove}
        >
            Remove
        </Button>
    );
};
```

I want to test that the button's `status` turn `busy` before becoming `selected` once the `onRemove` function resolves. How do I do this with user events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mock `onRemove` async function and resolve the promise manually after `setIsRemove(true)`. So that you can assert the `isRemoving` to be `true` firstly and assert it to be `false` after the promise is resolved.

`MyElement.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const MyElement = ({ onRemove }) => {
  const [isRemoving, setIsRemoving] = useState(false);

  const handleRemove = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setIsRemoving(true);
    onRemove().finally(() => setIsRemoving(false));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleRemove}>Remove</button>
      <p>{isRemoving ? 'busy' : 'selected'}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

`MyElement.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import { MyElement } from './MyElement';

describe('72858536', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    let _resolve;
    const onRemoveMock = () => new Promise((resolve) => (_resolve = resolve));
    render(<MyElement onRemove={onRemoveMock} />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/remove/i));
    expect(screen.getByText(/busy/)).toBeInTheDocument();
    _resolve();
    expect(await screen.findByText(/selected/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/72858536/MyElement.test.tsx
  72858536
    ✓ should pass (40 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyElement.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.778 s, estimated 16 s
```